# How to link a library from git submodule

Tags: c++, cmake, static-linking

Assume I want to use [QHotKey](https://github.com/Skycoder42/QHotkey) in my project. The source is checked out as git submdule. I tried:

```
add_subdirectory(QHotkey)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE qhotkey)
```

However QHotkey has an install section and on install QHotkey will be installed as well, although I only want to statically link. How do I correctly link QHotKey in my project?

Answer (score 0):

Based on their `CMakeLists.txt` file (line 44):

```
if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  target_compile_definitions(qhotkey PRIVATE QHOTKEY_LIBRARY)
  target_compile_definitions(qhotkey PUBLIC QHOTKEY_SHARED)
endif()
```

I would assume you need to:

```
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS FALSE)
```

To get a static library out of it. This is just based on what I skimmed through their CMakeLists. The install target is invoked only by calling `make install` but if you don't want it at all then you need to delete it from their `CMakeLists.txt`

EDIT: The other option that I've noticed a few times would be to use `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` flag when adding the subdirectory, bare in mind it might not be exactly what you want. Here is the [link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL.html)